# What happened to Unfied View in Thundbird 17?

Tags: thunderbird

I installed thunderbird 17 but I don't see any option to go to "unifed" view. Did they move it somewhere new or did they remove it?

Comment: You will have to ask the Thunderbird community and/or developer this question.  Of course the developement of Thunderbird has basically stopped.